# other phrases for "little investment, big return"?

Tags: phrases

Does anything come to mind as a more colloquial / non-business phrase instead of "little investment, big return"? Thanks!

Comment: how about *bang for your/the buck*? http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bang+for+the+buck

Comment: "*hit/get the jackpot*" for the "big return".

Comment: "*No pain, high gain*" extrapolated from "no pain, no gain".

Comment: *easy money*.   A *sure thing*.

Answer (score 2):

[**Mighty oaks from little acorns grow**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mighty_oaks_from_little_acorns_grow)

> Something great can come from a modest beginning

or, if talking about something negative...

[**Sow the wind and reap the whirlwind**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sow+the+wind+and+reap+the+whirlwind)

> to start some kind of trouble that grows much larger than you planned

Answer (score 1):

How about: "Big bang for the buck".  It's informal but gets the idea across well.

Answer (score 0):

"Pay dirt" you need to look it up.  People will say "I hit pay dirt!"

It is almost like "something for nothing."

And "buy short, sell long."  Stock Market term.

Answer (score 0):

**[Many a mickle makes a muckle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/many_a_mickle_makes_a_muckle)** (Scottish proverb)

many a little makes a mickle (also many a mickle makes a muckle): many small amounts accumulate to make a large amount. ([Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/pt/defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o/ingl%C3%AAs-americano/mickle))

Answer (score -1):

How about **more bang for your buck**?

Comment: Hi user141706 and welcome to ELU! This is a good suggestion, but you should consider adding a definition/reference to your answer.